# Should I scrape data and save to database to have access to anime data

Tags: javascript, database, web-scraping, puppeteer, mern

I am in the planning phase of building an anime web app that is centered around users being able to watch and download anime. I cannot find an API for this and am thinking about scraping the data from another anime site. Then  save it to a database. Also I will be using puppeteer

Comment: Ok, good to know. What is your question?

Comment: Thing is I was wondering if I should scrape the video links from a free site and then save it to database